# Split mySQL Query Results using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am working on a PHP function that looks up the list of departments in a school stored in a database table using MySQL and then splits the results into two columns if the result is more than 1 department.

I have tried for, while and foreach loops and for some reason I keep getting an endless loop as a result. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

My function is as follows:

```
function translateDegreeLists($school) {
require('includes/EM-langSelect-4.php');

$values = array();

$coacs_code = 1;
$cob_code = 2;
$avcon_code = 4;
$coe_code = 3;
$cose_code = 5;
$cotm_code = 6;

$query = "SELECT dept_name, ".$content." AS content FROM explore_majors.departments WHERE school_id = ".$school."";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$nums = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($nums == 1) {
        echo '1 Option';    
    } 
    elseif(($nums / 2) == 2) {
        echo '2 Columns with 2 Options';    
    } 
    elseif (($nums / 2) >= 3) {
        echo '2 Columns with more than 3 Options';  
    } 


echo '<div class="column column-1-2">';

    for ($i=0; $i < $nums; $i++) 
        { 
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $dept_name =     $row['content'];

            echo '<h4>'.$dept_name.'</h4>';
            echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>test</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        }

echo '</div>';
}
```

Note: The $content in the query is pulled from the EM-lang-4.php which determines the browser language and selects the appropriate column in the DB.

This is the base of the function as the code above generates a list of 4 departments all within the same column div.

The end result is that I want the function to calculate how many departments are found and if more than 1, split them equally between 2 divs. The divs will be identical with the exception of the content inside.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside you should no longer use mysql_*** functions, they are depreciated. See the red warning in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: Some suggestions: Switch on error reporting. Break your code into smaller functions. Take out bits of code until it works to identify where the issue is. Remember to close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are running mysql_fetch_assoc every time in the for loop. The loop should be structured as so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dept_name =     $row['content'];

  echo '<h4>'.$dept_name.'</h4>';
  echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li>test</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Note that this will not format the columns but you will at least be able to print the results of your query.

Php.net is your friend! See example one in the [documentation for mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Lastly mysql_*** functions are deprecated and will eventually be removed from future php versions! See the red warning in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)